# Google Sheets - Button to copy content from range of cells and register in the first blank row of another sheet

Tags: google-sheets

I found many questions regarding the same matter in Excel, however in Google Sheets it seems pretty limited. I want to create a button with an inserted AppScripts function to copy a range of cells in the same row as the button and paste it as values in the first blank row in another sheet.

In [this link is the Google Sheets sample](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/101b-gWADuicWVf38vKI1_8gQPnYgZeU3adH0-IocTyI/edit#gid=0).

What would be the best approach to this matter? How would the AppScript look like?

Comment: Can you clarify on this further? So by saying "I want to create a button..", does that mean you will be creating a button each time you will insert a new data in your sheet? Also, an apps script can be binded in a button/drawing in google sheets but I am not sure if this is possible for every new button that will be created as you still need to re-bind the script on the newly created button.

Comment: If you look at the sample you will see a column with a lot of "Register". I want to be able to click in that Register and copy all values in the row and paste it in the first blank row in the following sheet. Did I clear it?

Answer (score 2):

[This is a copy of your sample](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1sDoQ4X-YuINFNSH8dsguaqDypQqWfF0X5loYmGn1PeQ/edit#gid=127009148) created specifically for this question.

This is the code implemented on that sheet:

```
function onEdit(e){
register(e);
}

function register(e) {
  var sheet = e.range.getSheet();
  if(!e.value || e.range.getColumn()!=8 || sheet.getName()!='Database sheet'){return}
  e.range.clearContent();
  var ss = e.source;
  ss.getSheetByName(sheet.getRange('J1').getValue()).appendRow(sheet.getRange(e.range.getRow(),1,1,7).getValues()[0]);
}
```